# A copy of the value for @include

Tags: html, css, sass, scss-mixins

I have 2 mixins:

```
$sm: 560px;
$md: 768px;

@mixin sm {
    @media (max-width: $sm) {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin md {
    @media (min-width: #{$sm + 1}) and (max-width: $md - 1) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

I would like to merge these values, is it possible?
Example:

```
.example{

@include sm{
background: black;
}

@include md{
background: black;
}
}
```

replace to something like this (some shortcut like in normal css):

```
@include sm, @include md{
background: black;
}
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It should be your selector first and continue with { @include

```
.example {
 @include sm;
} 

@mixin sm{
  background-colour:black; }
```

Comment: not really what i want, sometimes couple of styles are the same for 2-3 mixins, and i don't want to unnecessary repeat them.